# Portrait mode touch not working with nvidia-515 driver

Tags: nvidia, 22.04, xorg, display-rotation

I have NUCXI7 device with Ubuntu 22.04 and have installed nvidia-515 driver on it. Everything works fine, however touch doesn't work when I change on Portrait mode.

I have also disabled WaylandEnable from Ubuntu, but it doesn't working in this case as well. Could someone please suggest if what is workaround to resolve the issue. Thanks!